# Discord.py Bot wont start, getting error "Main.run' was never awaited" but i dont know why I should await it

Tags: discord.py

```
class Main:

    def __init__(self):
        self.client = None

    async def register_commands(self):
        self.client.remove_command("help")

        await self.client.add_cog(BlacklistCommand(self.client))
        await self.client.add_cog(ClearCommand(self.client))
        await self.client.add_cog(DoxCommand(self.client))
        await self.client.add_cog(HelpCommand(self.client))
        await self.client.add_cog(InfoCommand(self.client))
        await self.client.add_cog(IpCommand(self.client))
        await self.client.add_cog(SlayerCommand(self.client))

    async def register_events(self):
        await self.client.add_cog(CommandErrorListener(self.client))
        await self.client.add_cog(OnMessageListener(self.client))
        await self.client.add_cog(OnReadyListener(self.client))

    async def run(self):
        token = json.load(open('files/apikeys.json'))['discord']['bot_token']

        intents = discord.Intents().all()

        self.client = commands.Bot("§", intents=intents, case_insensitive=True)

        await self.register_commands()
        await self.register_events()

        self.client.run(token)


Main().run()
```

I tried running it and it it just gave me an error message "

RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Main.run' was never awaited
Main().run()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Process finished with exit code 0"

Answer (score 0):

> but i dont know why I should await it

You should await it because you made the function async

```py
  async def run(self):
# ^^^^^  <- it's async, so it must be awaited
```

If you want to do any async setup, either make an async main or use the built-in `setup_hook` function.

The migration guide explains how to do both: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html?highlight=setup_hook#asyncio-event-loop-changes

Comment: When I edit the end
´´´
async def run():
    await Main().run()
´´´
Nothing happens "Process finished with exit code 0"

Comment: @Dr.Troll if you made a new async function called `run()`, are you actually calling it? Cause if nothing happens that suggests you just _made it_ but aren't actually using it

Comment: so how do i call it?

Comment: If you want to run an async main then you have to use `asyncio.run()`. However, your main calls `client.run()`, which already calls that, so you can't use it (`asyncio.run()` can't call itself). You can either have an async main, **or** use `client.run()`, but **not both at the same time**. Again, the docs link in my answer shows you how to do it both ways...